# Were there any terrestrial species in the ancestry of all crustaceans?

Tags: evolution, phylogenetics, biodiversity, arthropod

To the exception of woodlice, Crustaceans live in aquatic (marine or freshwater) environments. [Crustaceans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crustacean) are [arthropods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthropod) which is an immensely diverse taxon. Many arthropods live in terrestrial environments and many live in aquatic environments.

[Pisani et al (2004)](https://bmcbiol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1741-7007-2-1) report evidence of fossil of terrestrial arthropods as old as ~450 million years ago. According to [Wikipedia > Arthropoda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthropod) citing [Lin et al. (2007)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/08912960500508689) (the paper is behind a paywall, I could not read it myself) report evidence of fossil of arthropods as old as ~550 million years ago.

**Were there any terrestrial species in the ancestry of all crustaceans?**

Comment: Are you asking if all extant crustaceans descend from a terrestrial species?

Comment: Yes. Whether the MRCA of all crustaceans (or another organism in that lineage before that) was terrestrial.

Comment: There is free pdf from researchgate [(link)](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jih-Pai_Lin/publication/247494640_A_Parvancorina-like_arthropod_from_the_Cambrian_of_South_China/links/563b1d7308ae45b5d284c99d/A-Parvancorina-like-arthropod-from-the-Cambrian-of-South-China.pdf).